# pypy Ensure pip error ("C:\pypy3.exe -m ensurepip") windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, pip, windows-10, pypy

I am trying to install pypy pip installation howveer there is this bug when I try to run `pypy3 -m ensurepip` I have a 64bit windows 10 os system. I get this error when I try to run the program in cmd:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$EXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\util.py", line 192, in subst_vars
    return re.sub(r'\$([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)', _subst, s)
  File "C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$EXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\lib-python\3\re.py", line 194, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$EXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\util.py", line 189, in _subst
    return os.environ[var_name]
  File "C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$EXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\lib-python\3\os.py", line 681, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'EXa8572'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjdn5f_qd\pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjdn5f_qd\pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 185, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjdn5f_qd\pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 257, in run
    isolated_mode=options.isolated_mode,
  File "C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjdn5f_qd\pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 599, in decide_user_install
    if site_packages_writable(root=root_path, isolated=isolated_mode):
  File "C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjdn5f_qd\pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 544, in site_packages_writable
    test_writable_dir(d) for d in set(get_lib_location_guesses(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjdn5f_qd\pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 538, in get_lib_location_guesses
    scheme = distutils_scheme('', *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjdn5f_qd\pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\locations.py", line 125, in distutils_scheme
    i.finalize_options()
  File "C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$EXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\command\install.py", line 321, in finalize_options
    self.expand_basedirs()
  File "C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$EXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\command\install.py", line 495, in expand_basedirs
    self._expand_attrs(['install_base', 'install_platbase', 'root'])
  File "C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$EXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\command\install.py", line 489, in _expand_attrs
    val = subst_vars(val, self.config_vars)
  File "C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$EXa8572.21538\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\util.py", line 194, in subst_vars
    raise ValueError("invalid variable '$%s'" % var)
ValueError: invalid variable '$'EXa8572''**strong text**
```

Comment: Path: `\Temp\Rar$EXa8572.21538`; KeyError: **EXa8572**. It seems somehow the code doesn't like shell metacharacters (`$`) in the path.

Comment: I get the same error on CPython. PyPy is "bug for bug compatible" so it needs to be solved in CPython first.